Implementing Robin and Dirichlet boundary conditions
I am trying to solve this second order ODE.

This is done by utilizing these two boundary conditions, first being a Dirichlet boundary at one of the edge, xb.

The second boundary condition is the robin boundary condition at xo.

When I attempt to solve the code, its says that there is infinity power issue.
Here is the sample of my code
  (*Clear all global variables*)ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*General variables*)
xo = 0; (*Start of domain*)
xb = 7*10^-6; (*End of domain*)
beta = 2.39*10^20;
cbulk = 1; (*Bulk concentration boundary value*)
vfr = 7.24*10^-30;
vb = 7.24*10^-30;
na = 6.022*10^23;
vw = 2.99*10^-29;
vs = 7.24*10^-30;
delBind = 1*10^-6;
kbind = 100;
Dbulk = 10^-9;
B = 0.000001; (*Input parameter*)

(*Functions*)
cs[x_] := 0.1/2*(1 - Tanh[5000000*(x - 1*10^-6)]);
DelU[x_] := -10*((1 - Tanh[5000000*(x - 1*10^-6)]))/2;
phiP[x_] := 0.4*((1 - Tanh[5000000*(x - 3*10^-6)]));
Uext[x_] := -1/2*((1 - Tanh[5000000*(x - 3*10^-6)]));

(*Intermediate expressions for clarity*)
diffTerm[x_] := 
  Dbulk*((1 - phiP[x] - na*Cf[x]*vfr - na*vs*cs[x] - 
        na*vb*(na*cs[x]*Cf[x]*vw)/(Exp[DelU[x]] + 
            na*Cf[x]*vw))/(2 - (1 - phiP[x] - na*Cf[x]*vfr - 
          na*vs*cs[x] - 
          na*vb*(na*cs[x]*Cf[x]*vw)/(Exp[DelU[x]] + na*Cf[x]*vw))))^2;

uEffTerm[
   x_] := (Uext[x] - (vfr/vw)*
     Log[1 - phiP[x] - na*vs*cs[x] - na*vfr*Cf[x] - 
       na*vb*(na*cs[x]*Cf[x]*vw)/(Exp[DelU[x]] + na*Cf[x]*vw)]);

(*The modified DiffEq with Robin BC at x=0*)
DiffEqCf = D[- diffTerm[x]*Cf[x]*D[uEffTerm[x], x],x] == 0;

(*Boundary conditions for Cf[x] at x=xb and x=xo*)
BCs = {Cf[xo] == B/(kbind*delBind), 
   Cf[xb] = cbulk};  (*Robin condition at x=0*)

(*Solve the system using NDSolve*)
sol = NDSolve[{DiffEqCf, BCs}, Cf[x], {x, xo, xb}];

(*Extract the solution for Cf[x]*)
CfSol = Cf[x] /. sol[[1]];

(*Plot the solution*)
Plot[CfSol, {x, xo, xb}]


Have you seen the system functions DirichletCondition and NeumannValue? The NeumannValue can also represent a Robin boundary condition.

what kind of physics problem is this where you have to work with such small quantities as vw = 2.9910^-29; vs = 7.2410^-30; ?

This problem involves the diffusion of drug molecules into a hydrogel system
